# Magento2 cloud fastly bypass specific URL

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud, fastly

I've a magento 2 commerce site(hosted on magento cloud, it is using fastly full page cache) when it saving customer additional address, it will show

```
The requested URL was rejected.

For additional information, please contact support and provide this reference ID:

ca021a552d6bc561cc2e95e626ee68c2750f4ac24571eb1fc249a0941832b1ea

Go Back
```

Here is the target form post action

https://www.example.com/customer/address/formPost/id/1450/

Is it possible to set about url (https://www.example.com/customer/address/formPost/*) bypass fastly cache?

Answer (score 0):

Fastly automatically bypasses all POST requests, so if this error happens on a form submit, it gets to the backend and the error happens there. Did you check your exception log and Apache / Nginx error logs?

Comment: Seems not, i add the real server ip and web site domain in the hosts file in my work station, the form has no error, so i completely no idea.

Comment: hey @hkguile  i have the same exact error with the same environment, did you get the solution, if yes, please post here, it will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastly WAF blocking your request and they (adobe/fastly) need to update the WAF config or you could technically bypass this with a custom vcl snippet if you know the exact route.

The comment about Fastly bypassing POST requests is wrong.